# Authorize mvc acceso de usuarios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy implementando el uso de permisos de usuario con el `Authorize`, he implementado correctamente su funcionamiento, pero quisiera saber cómo hago que cuando el usuario no esté autorizado a acceder a esa vista en el controlador `Authorize` no me redirija al login si no a una ventana de advertencia que no tiene los permisos:

```
public class UnidadesController : Controller
{
    SidcarEntities1 db = new SidcarEntities1();
    // GET: Unidades
    [Authorize(Users = "Usuario1, Usuario2")]
    public ActionResult Arope()
    {
        List<Departamento> DepartamentoList = db.Departamentos.ToList();
        ViewBag.DepartamentoList = new SelectList(DepartamentoList, "IdDepartamento", "Departamento1");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero te refieres en el caso de que esté logueado PERO no tenga permisos para acceder ¿no?

Comment: Si exacto ya el usuario esta logueado y tiene permisos a ciertas vistas pero si intenta acceder a cierta vista pues en vez de dirigirlo al login salga una ventana tipo mensaje que no esta autorizado

Comment: Como haces la llamada a la accion?

Answer (score 1):

Opción buena, buena no hay hasta donde yo se. El atributo Authorize devuelve un código 401 independientemente de que el usuario esté o no logueado. Soluciones  que he usado otras veces:
Opción 1- Crear tu propio atributo que herede de Authorize, en el que compruebes si está o no logueado y devuelvas Forbidden o Unauthorized según sea el caso :

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Opción 2- (Más fea aun), en el Login añades una condición para checkear si el usuario esta autenticado o no. Si está autenticado y lo han redirigido al Login, entonces das por sentado que es que no está autorizado para hacer lo que pretendía a hacer y lo rediriges a una vista propia que te hagas con el mensaje de "No tienes permisos blablablbla"

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos maneras, la primera y la más viable es

1. Validar la sesión a través de un `FilterAttribute`
2. Únicamente hacer uso de la anotación `[Authorize]`

## 1. Usando un `FilterAttribute`

Puedes implementar un `FilterAttribute` donde podrás validar si el usuario está autenticado. Primero debes crear una clase `ValidateAuthenticationFilterAttribute` que herede de `ActionFilterAttribute`, y si el usuario no se ha autenticado se deberá hacer una redirección a la página de permiso denegado (suponiendo que tu Controller se llama Permisos y el Action es Denegado):

```
public class ValidateAuthenticationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (/*Aquí validas si el usuario tiene los permisos*/)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Permisos", action = "Denegado" }));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Finalmente, en el Controler sol deberás poner la anotación `[ValidateAuthenticationFilter]`:

```
[ValidateAuthenticationFilter]
public class UnidadesController : Controller
{
    //TO DO
}
```

## 2. Usando la anotación `[Authorize]`

Si el usuario no esta logueado en el sistema y se hace uso de esta anotación, la aplicación hará una redirección al *Controller* y el *Action* declarados por *default* en el archivo App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
[Authorize]
public class UnidadesController : Controller
{
    //TO DO
}
```

Comment: usted es un grande :D

Comment: @fredyfx son sus enseanzas maestro :D

Comment: gracias por el halago hermano, seguimos siendo aprendices :)

Comment: Pero eso no resuelve su problema. Él habla de un usuario actualmente autentificado pero que a pesar de ello carece de autorización para acceder a la vista. Por eso no le sirve el atributo Authorized, porque aunque estés autentificado, sino tienes los permisos adecuados, lo que hace el atributo es redirigir al login.

Comment: @S.Bonet sí y no, he actualizado mi respuesta para que quedara un poco más claro

Comment: Estoy mirando la respuesta pero no me logro entender quizas con lo que quiero hacer, tambien he pensado es que ese usuario no pueda ver en la vista el control que dirige a ese controlador

Comment: @JagerRubio te veo en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)